# Cannot pass the "Preparing to play..." (Samsung Allshare)

Tags: smart-tv

After some time investigating how this software/network connectivity works, I finally could link both PC and TV (Samsung EH6030) together, they see each other now, the TV is connect to a router, and internet also works on it.

The problem is, when I'm about to make the final step under View -> Player Control Screen Mode and play the movie in the TV from my PC, I get a `Preparing to play..` message just under the movie tittle, then after some seconds it says: `Remote player cannot play content, check network connectivity`. And that is all. Sometimes I don't even get an error, I just waits for like 20 seconds then nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: What type of video file are you trying to play?

Comment: A movie, MKV file.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung TVs do not natively support `.MKV` files but try to rename the extension to `.MP4` and see if it will play.

Comment: Mhhh that's weird, when I plug a pendrive with an mkv file it works perfectly. Until now I didn't have any issues with any kind of file.